# Converting ROS image to QImage

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm making a Qt based GUI for our ROS application and part of it is to display images from a ROS topic.

I've managed to create a descendant class of QLabel that displays an RGB image from our cameras (/camera/image_raw topic) but when I try to display a grayscale image /camera/image_mono) I get weird results.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
img_format_table = {'rgb8': QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888, 'mono8': QtGui.QImage.Format_Mono}

...

    def up_camera_callback(self, data):
        try:
            format = img_format_table[data.encoding]

            image = QtGui.QImage(data.data, data.width, data.height, format)
            self.up_camera_signal.emit(image)

        except Exception, e:
            rospy.logerr(e)
```

The up_camera_signal is connected to my "video display" widget and just displays the image on it. As I said, this works fine for RGB images (when the data.encoding is 'rgb8') but if I do this for 'mono8' images I see strange results:

[image: image description]

I have also tried mapping 'mono8' to QtGui.QImage.Format_MonoLSB but that doesn't change anything (documentation for the QImage formatting is at http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html).

Can anyone comment on this? Is there anything specific about the mono8 format in ROS that might be causing these problems?

Kind regards,
Stefan Freyr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38464/converting-ros-image-to-qimage/) by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no direct experience with either `QImage`s or ROS image data, but reading the `QImage` documentation -- and specifically [QImage#image-formats](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#image-formats) -- I came across this:

> Monochrome images are stored using 1-bit indexes into a color table with at most two colors.

Looking at some code in various ROS packages that deals with `mono8` images, it does not seem that ROS uses paletted images, which could explain your strange results.

---

Hm, AFAICT `mono8` isn't actually monochrome, but more like 8bit greyscale. According to [QImage#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.Format](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.Format) QImage does not support 8bit images, at least not without a palette. Perhaps you need to convert the `mono8` image to a 16bit or 32bit pp image first?

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on the encoding of the image you have to support multiple conversions. Here `mono8` and `bgr8` images are supported:

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg)
{
  QImage::Format format;
  if (msg->encoding == "mono8")
    format = QImage::Format_Grayscale8;
  else if (msg->encoding == "bgr8")
    // There is no BGR format in Qt; B and R channels will be inverted later
    format = QImage::Format_RGB888;
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Image pixel format not supported!");
    return;
  }

  QImage source_image(&msg->data[0], msg->width, msg->height, format);
  if (msg->encoding == "bgr8") // From RGB8 to BGR8
    source_image = source_image.rgbSwapped();

  if (source_image.isNull())
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Failed to read image");
    return;
  }

  // Use image ...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NordThor](https://answers.ros.org/users/53534/nordthor/) on 2020-04-14**:
Hi. The [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-4)  for QImage used in your answer assumes the data is 32-bit aligned. Alternative use `QImage source_image(&msg->data[0], msg->width, msg->height, msg->step, format);`  to support data that are aligned differently